# Object doesn't support this property or method error

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Ruby on rails application i installed jquery.
From then onwards i am getting this error

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 51
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://172.30.11.167:3000/javascripts/application.js?1315836568
```

Line 51 in application.js corresponds to

```
$('textarea.autoresize').autoResize({
      onResize : function() {$(this).css({opacity:0.8});},
      animateCallback : function() {$(this).css({opacity:1});},
      limit: 300
  }).change();
```

The code was working fine before. I am not sure if my installation of jquery caused the error.

Comment: juery.aotoresize.js is present in public/javascripts.I have not included jquery.js anywhere

Comment: Add   <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.min' %> and check again

Comment: Hi it already included in my defaults .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are experiencing Prototype vs jQuery selector conflict. Considering you are including jquery in your header, try this

```
jQuery('textarea.autoresize')
```